# Why do some teach Biblical Hebrew with modern verb tenses?

Tags: learning-methods, hebrew

I have noticed that some instructors teach Biblical Hebrew verbs with modern tenses (avar, atid, hoveh, tsivuy) when really there are only two forms (not tenses), perfect and imperfect.  I'm aware that the forms have evolved to be more compatible with modern language in Modern Hebrew and that this convention has been around for some time (since the Mishnah?) however it seems anachronistic to teach the tenses in context to the ancient form of Hebrew which had no conception of them.  Anyone else seen this?  Understand why?  Is it just for ease of explanation to students?